# Is the null matrix a regular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-calculus

I see there are different qualities of a regular matrix depending on definition. Is the null matrix (nxn) regular in any of them ?

Comment: The only meaning for "regular" that I have seen is invertible.  Do you have an example of another meaning that is in use?

Comment: I found the following definition of a regular matrix in my uni script stating that A is regular when: $Ax=b,\,\, x\in\mathbb{R}^n,\,\,x\neq 0,\,\, A\in\mathbb{R}^{nxn}$ this I now see goes back to the determinant not equal zero condition (and then invertibility).

Comment: After that i saw on the German wiki page for invertible matrices that if the matrix is defined over a commutative Ring then the determinant must only be in $\mathbb{R}$, and not $\neq 0$ which made me wonder if the definitions for a "regular" matrix vary but apparently not so much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular matrix is nonsingular (has an inverse).  The zero matrix is not invertible.  So, no, the zero matrix is not regular.

Answer (score 1):

All definitions of a regular matrix are equivalent, so no, the zero matrix will never be regular.